# Can I get the model or model name from a strapi request context?

Tags: strapi

I am building a policy in a Strapi instance. I want it to be a global policy that I can apply anywhere in the app, but I'll need to evaluate the model specific to the endpoint being requested. For example if I put this policy on a "restaurants" endpoint, I want to be able to make a query on the "restaurant" model.

The request of course would be something to the effect of "POST /restaurants/1234" And I know I could do a string split on the forward slash and drop the "s" from the end of restaurants. But I want to know is there a better supported way of converting the restaurants url into the actual serviceable model name?

Comment: I am not sure of what you want to do, but it seems that looking into `strapi.models` can do the job if you would like to access the collection or API programmatically.
Try a console.log(strapi.models) that will return a big array of model objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by parsing the route handler. Not sure if this is a cleaner way.

```
module.exports = async (ctx, config, { strapi }) => {
    let handler = ctx.state.route.handler;
    let modelName = handler.substring(0, handler.lastIndexOf("."));

    const entities = await strapi.db.query(modelName).findMany({
       where: {
          owner: ctx.state.user.id,
       },
    });
};
```